# How can i use json normalize to get down to multiple levels?

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize

I have a large json file that needs to be parsed into a dataframe. Here is an example of the data structure...

```
{
  "genericTags": [
    {
      "appliesTo": [
        "program",
        "email_batch",
        "nurture",
        "event",
        "webinar"
      ],
      "name": "Language",
      "type": null,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "Chinese",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "English",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "French",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "Japanese",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "Portuguese",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "Spanish",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        }
      ],
      "description": null
    },
    {
      "appliesTo": [
        "program",
        "email_batch",
        "nurture",
        "webinar",
        "event"
      ],
      "name": "Product",
      "type": null,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "P1",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "P2",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "P3",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "P4",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "P5",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "P6",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "P7",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "P8",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "P9",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "P10",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "P11",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "P12",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "Multiple",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "None",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        }
      ],
      "description": null
    },
    {
      "appliesTo": [
        "program",
        "email_batch",
        "nurture",
        "event",
        "webinar"
      ],
      "name": "Region",
      "type": null,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "Americas",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "APJ",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "EMEA",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        },
        {
          "value": "WW",
          "hidden": false,
          "deleted": false
        }
      ],
      "description": null
    }
  ],
  "channelTags": [
    {
      "value": "Advertising",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Advertising",
        "type": "program",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 20,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Association",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Association",
        "type": "program",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 20,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Contact Request",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Contact Request",
        "type": "program",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Sent Email",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 20,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 30,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Content",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Content",
        "type": "program",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 20,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Content Syndication",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Content Syndication",
        "type": "program",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 20,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Direct Mail",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Direct Mail",
        "type": "program",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 20,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Display",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Display",
        "type": "program",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 20,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Email",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Email",
        "type": "program",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 20,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Email Send",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Email Send",
        "type": "email_batch",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 20,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Event",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Event",
        "type": "event",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": false,
            "isUsed": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Invited",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": false,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Registered",
            "type": "Registered",
            "typeName": "registered",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 5,
            "order": 20,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": false,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Waitlisted",
            "type": "Waitlisted",
            "typeName": "wait_listed",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 4,
            "order": 20,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": false,
            "isUsed": false
          },
          {
            "name": "No Show",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 30,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": false,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Attended",
            "type": "Attended",
            "typeName": "attended",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 7,
            "order": 40,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": false,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Attended Session",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 50,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": false,
            "isUsed": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Intent Signal",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Intent Signal",
        "type": "program",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 20,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Interactive Chat",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Interactive Chat",
        "type": "program",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 20,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "value": "List Import",
      "progression": {
        "name": "List Import",
        "type": "program",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 20,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Nurture",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Nurture",
        "type": "nurture",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 20,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Converted",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 30,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": false
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Nurture Cast",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Nurture Cast",
        "type": "program",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Excluded",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 20,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Converted",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 30,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 30,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    },
    {
      "value": "Operational",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Operational",
        "type": "program",
        "description": null,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": true,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": false
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 10,
            "success": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": null,
            "typeId": null,
            "order": 20,
            "success": true,
            "hidden": true,
            "system": false,
            "isEventCapSet": null,
            "isUsed": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": false,
      "deleted": false
    }
  ]
}
```

What i am needing is specifically the channelTags array which i have currently broken out like this...

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# open json file
with open('file_name.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

# turn json into df and get channelTags array
df_channel = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['channelTags'])
```

This is resulting in the following data structure...

| value | hidden | deleted | progression.name | progression.type | progression.description | progression.steps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Advertising | False | False | Advertising | program | null | [{'name': 'Not in Program', 'type': 'Not in Program', 'typeName': 'not_in_program', 'description': None, 'typeId': 1, 'order': 0, 'success': False, 'hidden': False, 'system': True, 'isEventCapSet': None, 'isUsed': False}, {'name': 'Member', 'description': None, 'typeId': None, 'order': 10, 'success': False, 'hidden': False, 'system': False, 'isEventCapSet': None, 'isUsed': True}, {'name': 'Engaged', 'description': None, 'typeId': None, 'order': 20, 'success': True, 'hidden': False, 'system': False, 'isEventCapSet': None, 'isUsed': True}] |
| Trade Show | False | False | Trade Show | event | null | [{'name': 'Not in Program', 'type': 'Not in Program', 'typeName': 'not_in_program', 'description': None, 'typeId': 1, 'order': 0, 'success': False, 'hidden': False, 'system': True, 'isEventCapSet': False, 'isUsed': False}, {'name': 'Invited', 'description': None, 'typeId': None, 'order': 10, 'success': False, 'hidden': False, 'system': False, 'isEventCapSet': False, 'isUsed': True}, {'name': 'Registered', 'type': 'Registered', 'typeName': 'registered', 'description': None, 'typeId': 5, 'order': 20, 'success': False, 'hidden': False, 'system': False, 'isEventCapSet': False, 'isUsed': True}, {'name': 'Waitlisted', 'type': 'Waitlisted', 'typeName': 'wait_listed', 'description': None, 'typeId': 4, 'order': 20, 'success': False, 'hidden': False, 'system': False, 'isEventCapSet': False, 'isUsed': False}, {'name': 'No Show', 'description': None, 'typeId': None, 'order': 30, 'success': False, 'hidden': False, 'system': False, 'isEventCapSet': False, 'isUsed': False}, {'name': 'Attended Show', 'type': 'Attended', 'typeName': 'attended', 'description': None, 'typeId': 7, 'order': 40, 'success': False, 'hidden': False, 'system': False, 'isEventCapSet': False, 'isUsed': True}, {'name': 'Visited Booth', 'description': None, 'typeId': None, 'order': 50, 'success': True, 'hidden': False, 'system': False, 'isEventCapSet': False, 'isUsed': True}, {'name': 'Attended Hosted Event', 'description': None, 'typeId': None, 'order': 60, 'success': True, 'hidden': False, 'system': False, 'isEventCapSet': False, 'isUsed': True}] |

I still need to be able to go one step further down to parse out the progression.steps. I have accomplished this somewhat by using the following...

```
df_normal = pd.json_normalize(df_channel['progression'], 'steps', errors='ignore')
```

This code results in the following...

| name | type | typeName | description | typeId | order | success | hidden | system | isEventCapSet | IsUsed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Not in Program | Not in Program | Not in Program | null | 1 | 0 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | null | FALSE |
| Member | null | null | null | null | 10 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | null | FALSE |
| Engaged | null | null | null | null | 20 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | null | FALSE |

What i am missing is the ability to combine these two dataframes as i do not have a key field, the end result should be the df_channel dataframe and the df_normal dataframe combined with a left join on a df_channel['value'] entry.

What am i missing here?

Comment: `json-normalize` works with lists of dicts, not dicts of dicts.

Comment: Try using `concat` (and maybe `explode` as well).  ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70626765/2956135

Comment: @AmmarAldabbagh okay so what would i need to do in order to get my desired result?

Comment: the example of the data you put in your question is not valid dictionary

Comment: @khaledkoubaa i have updated the json, however the full file is too large as it passes 30k characters. Hopefully that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

starting from a sample dictionary `data` as below:

```
data = {
  "genericTags": [
    {
      "appliesTo": [
        "program",
        "email_batch",
        "nurture",
        "event",
        "webinar"
      ],
      "name": "Language",
      "type": None,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "Chinese",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "English",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "French",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "Japanese",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "Portuguese",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "Spanish",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        }
      ],
      "description": None
    },
    {
      "appliesTo": [
        "program",
        "email_batch",
        "nurture",
        "webinar",
        "event"
      ],
      "name": "Product",
      "type": None,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "P1",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "P2",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "P3",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "P4",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "P5",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "P6",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "P7",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "P8",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "P9",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "P10",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "P11",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "P12",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "Multiple",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "None",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        }
      ],
      "description": None
    },
    {
      "appliesTo": [
        "program",
        "email_batch",
        "nurture",
        "event",
        "webinar"
      ],
      "name": "Region",
      "type": None,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": "Americas",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "APJ",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "EMEA",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        },
        {
          "value": "WW",
          "hidden": False,
          "deleted": False
        }
      ],
      "description": None
    }
  ],
  "channelTags": [
    {
      "value": "Advertising",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Advertising",
        "type": "program",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": False
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 20,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    },
    {
      "value": "Association",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Association",
        "type": "program",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": False
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 20,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    },
    {
      "value": "Contact Request",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Contact Request",
        "type": "program",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": False
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Sent Email",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 20,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 30,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    },
    {
      "value": "Content",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Content",
        "type": "program",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": False
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 20,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    },
    {
      "value": "Content Syndication",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Content Syndication",
        "type": "program",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": False
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 20,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    },
    {
      "value": "Direct Mail",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Direct Mail",
        "type": "program",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": False
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 20,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    },
    {
      "value": "Display",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Display",
        "type": "program",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": False
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 20,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    },
    {
      "value": "Email",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Email",
        "type": "program",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 20,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    },
    {
      "value": "Email Send",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Email Send",
        "type": "email_batch",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 20,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    },
    {
      "value": "Event",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Event",
        "type": "event",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": False,
            "isUsed": False
          },
          {
            "name": "Invited",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": False,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Registered",
            "type": "Registered",
            "typeName": "registered",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 5,
            "order": 20,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": False,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Waitlisted",
            "type": "Waitlisted",
            "typeName": "wait_listed",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 4,
            "order": 20,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": False,
            "isUsed": False
          },
          {
            "name": "No Show",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 30,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": False,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Attended",
            "type": "Attended",
            "typeName": "attended",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 7,
            "order": 40,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": False,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Attended Session",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 50,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": False,
            "isUsed": True
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    },
    {
      "value": "Intent Signal",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Intent Signal",
        "type": "program",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": False
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 20,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    },
    {
      "value": "Interactive Chat",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Interactive Chat",
        "type": "program",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": False
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 20,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    },
    {
      "value": "List Import",
      "progression": {
        "name": "List Import",
        "type": "program",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": False
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 20,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    },
    {
      "value": "Nurture",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Nurture",
        "type": "nurture",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 20,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Converted",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 30,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": False
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    },
    {
      "value": "Nurture Cast",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Nurture Cast",
        "type": "program",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Excluded",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 20,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Converted",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 30,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 30,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    },
    {
      "value": "Operational",
      "progression": {
        "name": "Operational",
        "type": "program",
        "description": None,
        "steps": [
          {
            "name": "Not in Program",
            "type": "Not in Program",
            "typeName": "not_in_program",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": 1,
            "order": 0,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": True,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": False
          },
          {
            "name": "Member",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 10,
            "success": False,
            "hidden": False,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          },
          {
            "name": "Engaged",
            "description": None,
            "typeId": None,
            "order": 20,
            "success": True,
            "hidden": True,
            "system": False,
            "isEventCapSet": None,
            "isUsed": True
          }
        ]
      },
      "hidden": False,
      "deleted": False
    }
  ]
}
```

try:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data['channelTags'])

df = df.merge(pd.concat(df['progression.steps'].apply(pd.DataFrame).tolist(), keys=df.index), how='left')
```

Comment: got a key error for 'progression .steps'

Comment: it's ```progression.steps``` without space before the ```.steps```. make sude it's tiped correctly: ```df['progression.steps']``` not ```df['progression. steps']```

Comment: sorry that was a typo in the comment. should have double checked it

Comment: after ```df = pd.json_normalize(data['channelTags'])```, what you got when you do ```print(df.columns)``` ?

Comment: okay so i re-ran your solution and it seems to be combining every  possible channel tag with every possible step. 

For exmaple: the advertising channel tag only has three step records. the solution you gave has it at 107 (which is the total step records)

Comment: ```
Index(['value', 'hidden', 'deleted', 'progression.name', 'progression.type',
       'progression.description', 'progression.steps', 'name', 'type',
       'typeName', 'description', 'typeId', 'order', 'success', 'system',
       'isEventCapSet', 'isUsed'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: @DerekGunn so, it works like you want ?

Comment: Hi Khaled, I'm needing the channelTag to be matched up with the proper steps. for example: Advertising would have Not in Program, Member, and Engaged. So only three rows

Comment: you means the new added data are all duplicates (same 3 rows repeat again and again) ?

Comment: no like its making every single possible combination of all of the channels and all of the steps. 

I ended up with over 3k rows. I believe it should be 107

Comment: @DerekGunn I don't understand clearly, can you put a clarification or example in your answer ?

Comment: im getting a shape of 3024 X 17, should be 107x17. 

so what seems be to happening is that the apply function is not matching the value with the proper progression.steps. it is combining everything

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data) #all data. there are two columns: genericTags and channelTags

import json
to_json = json.loads(df.to_json(orient="records"))    
df_v1 = pd.json_normalize(to_json)

mask = df_v1.explode('genericTags.values', ignore_index=True)
final=mask.join(pd.DataFrame([*mask.pop('genericTags.values')], index=mask.index))
final.columns=final.columns + '_'  #for second step. because there are columns with the same name.

final_mask = final.explode('channelTags.progression.steps_', ignore_index=True)

final=final_mask.join(pd.DataFrame([*final_mask.pop('channelTags.progression.steps_')], index=final_mask.index))
```

Comment: Hi Clegane, 

This seems to be throwing a value error because the genericTags are not the same length as the channelTags. I'm only needing the channelTags which is why i removed the channelTags